# Jersey app deployment error

Tags: rest, jersey, servlet-3.0

I have a simple jersey based REST Web service where i'm trying to do a test GET run..

Using Jersey 2.7 & Servlet 3.0 container, I have tried configuring the application using the jersey doc ( [JAX-RS application without an Application subclass](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3)

I have defined a resource

```
@Path("/bolt")
public class SpringRequestResource extends BaseResource {

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getHello() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

And my deployment descriptor web.xml as

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<display-name>Alpha</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However, upon throwing a GET request via browser through a url **[http://myName.xyz.com:6080/[projectName]/myService/bolt](http://myName.xyz.com:6080/%5bprojectName%5d/myService/bolt)** 
It throws the following exception -

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:851)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:278)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:270)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:218)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:448)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:309)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:168)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:851)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:278)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can't seem to figure out the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue with Jersey 2.9. You can try to migrate to Jersey 2.9. If it does not help you can create an new issue in https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY as this is probably a bug and not your fault. It would be good if you could attach a simple reproducible test case (simple executable maven project that reproduces the problem).

The workaround would be to use extension of Application class or ResourceConfig to configure the application.

Comment: I had problems with Jersey 2.9 as well.. Eventually, I had to resort to the old way of defining servlet with org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer class and passing it a provider package